# Check to see if JMS message was sent

Tags: jms, spring-jms

What is the best practice to know if a message that is sent via jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator()....

I have an async process where a message is delivered to a queue, then some other third party process picks up the message.

What is best practice to know if the message was delivered, or in a case such as this is it normal to only check for errors?

Comment: do you want to know if the message was sent (title) or if it was received (body)?

Comment: normal is to only check for errors